# Dynatree is stuck loading the icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I use dynatree to display a list of documents. When I load the template, the dynatree was stuck in the loading icon. What could be wrong?

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
checkbox: true,
selectMode: 2,
initAjax: {
  url: "/getTree/",
  dataType: "json",
  data:  {}
},
onSelect: function(node) {
     },
onActivate: function (node) {
},
persist: true,
noLink: false,
fx: { height: "toggle", duration: 200 },
onPostInit: function (isReloading, isError) {
    if (getStringOfSelectedTreeNodes() != '') {
             }
 }
 }); }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an example maybe on CodePen to check what the issue is. It seems the last }); end braces was not needed, was this because it was within a jQuery $(document).ready(); method. Otherwise this would be the correct code: Some good examples on the [dynatree example page](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) which I'm sure you've seen.

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
  checkbox: true,
  selectMode: 2,
  initAjax: {
    url: "/getTree/",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  {}
  },
  onSelect: function(node) {
  },
  onActivate: function (node) {
  },
  persist: true,
  noLink: false,
  fx: { height: "toggle", duration: 200 },
  onPostInit: function (isReloading, isError) {
    if (getStringOfSelectedTreeNodes() != '') {
    }
  }
});
```